# swift delete image file, throw file does not exist

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, nsfilemanager

```
 let filename = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent(upload.fileName)
               print("deleting")
            let fileNameToDelete = upload.fileName
            var filePath = ""          
            // Fine documents directory on device
            let dirs : [String] = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.allDomainsMask, true)          
            if dirs.count > 0 {
                let dir = dirs[0] //documents directory
                filePath = dir.appendingFormat("/" + fileNameToDelete)
                print("Local path = \(filePath)")      
            } else {
                print("Could not find local directory to store file")
                return
            }         
            print(filename)           
              print("deleting111111")
            do {
                let fileManager = FileManager.default  
                // Check if file exists
                print("filePath")
                print(filePath)
                 print("filePath")
                if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: filePath) {
                    // Delete file
                    try fileManager.removeItem(atPath: filePath)
                } else {
                    print("File does not exist")
                }            
            }
            catch let error as NSError {
                print("An error took place: \(error)")
            }}
```

This gets printed below. Why is delete not working? Why is above function throwing to me on file exists it does not exist

```
deleting
Local path = /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/C763B3ED-3371-47AB-8F61-4F086D01E430/Documents/profile-FFCEBEA9-2F8D-49E2-9A09-2BF87BD0B542--A9636AF4-350D-4D72-A4BD-E4F2B183F4BB.png
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/C763B3ED-3371-47AB-8F61-4F086D01E430/Documents/profile-FFCEBEA9-2F8D-49E2-9A09-2BF87BD0B542--A9636AF4-350D-4D72-A4BD-E4F2B183F4BB.png
deleting111111
filePath
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/C763B3ED-3371-47AB-8F61-4F086D01E430/Documents/profile-FFCEBEA9-2F8D-49E2-9A09-2BF87BD0B542--A9636AF4-350D-4D72-A4BD-E4F2B183F4BB.png
filePath
File does not exist
```

Comment: D o e s the file exist?

Comment: it should, because i save it using  this  below..

Comment: func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
        let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
        return documentsDirectory
    }

Comment: let filename = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent(nameOfImage+".PNG")
            try? image_data?.write(to: filename)

Comment: and a local file path is printed here print("Local path = \(filePath)")      correctly i think. it does not give me Could not find local directory to store file

Comment: `.png` != `.PNG` – iOS is case sensitive

Comment: makes no difference

Answer (score 0):

If you created the file by writing to a filename generated with

```
filename = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent(nameOfImage+"‌​.PNG")
```

...then it is *absolutely crucial* that, when the time comes to delete the file, you generate the filename in exactly the same way. That is not what you are doing.

Indeed, in the code you have shown, you do generate a variable called `filename` with code that looks similar:

```
let filename = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent(upload.fileName)
```

...but then you never *use* `filename` for anything! Thus you keep faking yourself out. You create `filename`, you print `filename`, but you do not use `filename` as the path to delete. You use some other variable, `filePath`, obtained in a different way.

Comment: Also, `dir.appendingFormat("/" + fileNameToDelete)` is a terrible way to work with a file path.

Comment: In my opinion, it would be far better to use file URLs throughout and work entirely with URL methods. Obtain the documents directory with this method: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/filemanager/1407693-url and work entirely from there. String filepaths are the work of the devil; that is why URLs are preferred.

Answer (score 0):

put your remove code in DispatchQueue.main.async like this:

```
let filename = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent(upload.fileName)
           print("deleting")
        let fileNameToDelete = upload.fileName
        var filePath = ""          
        // Fine documents directory on device
        let dirs : [String] = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.allDomainsMask, true)          
        if dirs.count > 0 {
            let dir = dirs[0] //documents directory
            filePath = dir.appendingFormat("/" + fileNameToDelete)
            print("Local path = \(filePath)")      
        } else {
            print("Could not find local directory to store file")
            return
        }         
        print(filename)           
          print("deleting111111")
        do {
            let fileManager = FileManager.default  
            // Check if file exists
            print("filePath")
            print(filePath)
             print("filePath")
            if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: filePath) {
                // Delete file

                DispatchQueue.main.async { // <- here
                  try fileManager.removeItem(atPath: filePath)
                }
                
            } else {
                print("File does not exist")
            }            
        }
        catch let error as NSError {
            print("An error took place: \(error)")
        }}
```